# python selenium data-style-name

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

So there's a bit of html that looks like this

```
<a class="" data-style-name="Black" data-style-id="16360" "true" data-description="null"<img width="32" height="32"
```

and I was wondering if I could get the text "Black" out of it and than click it, but there's no class name too loop through and the xpath doesn't return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-style-name` is called an attribute of your `a` element and "Black" is its value.

Here is a way to access attribute's value with selenium & python:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-style-name]")
for element in elements:
    print element.get_attribute("data-style-name")
```

If you want to select only elements with attribute `data-style-name` with value "Black":

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-style-name=Black]")
```

---

More about xpath: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction

Comment: What is .getAttribute? I says it's not a function

Comment: hey this only does it for one of the boxes and I can't click them any idea?

Comment: Can you paste somewhere the HTML source of the page please ? Or give the link ? I'm not sure to understand what you are struggling on.

Comment: Not sure if I understood, but if you have several items you want to parse in the same page, you can use `find_elements_by_xpath` (note the "s"), which should returns a list of elements. So you can loop on it and extract _all_ values

Comment: ah right of course, should've thought of that. Thanks

Comment: colors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-style-name]").get_attribute("data-style-name")
print(colors) , I didn't loop through it but I get this AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute', even when looping through it @Arount

Comment: Because `find_elements_by_xpath` returns **list** of elements. You have to loop in to access elements which exposes `get_attribute` method. Just like in example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try on `find_element_by_xpath()`?

```
a_check = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/a[@data-style-name='Black']")
```

Which returns:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6c94ac24e0ec3a3320ec21b24055f4fa", element="0.1043557711542944-1")>
```